# How to determine in the APDU command from which position to execute READ RECORD?

Tags: apdu, emv

I'm trying to get the PAN from different cards (VISA, MASTERCARD). I can't understand how to form a READ RECORD command, as it may differ for each card.

Here's the sequence I have after receiving the card's ATS:

1. Using the command 2PAY.SYS.DDF01: 00A404000E325041592E5359532E4444463031, I obtain the card's AID.
2. I perform a SELECT based on the obtained AID: 0A0000A4040007A0000000031010.
3. I execute READ RECORD: 00 B2 **P1 P2** 00.
   For different cards, **P1 P2** are different, for example:
   00 B2 **01 0C** 00
   00 B2 **03 14** 00
   00 B2 **02 14** 00
   00 B2 **01 14** 00

How can I determine in advance what values of **P1 P2** should be used for the current card in the READ RECORD command, and what are their initial and final values?

---

The approximate response to my own question has been formed. But I'm not sure if it's correct (and even if it is correct, I still have a problem with obtaining GPO or GET DATA).

Did I understand correctly that: P1 is the record number, and P2 is some kind of identifier for the file? And in order for us to know these P1 and P2 values, we need a list of SFIs, and SFIs, in turn, are obtained using GPO or GET DATA? If so, then I tried to do GPO and GET DATA, but I get an error 6A 81 on these actions. Here is the GPO command: 80CA000000 which I do immediately after SELECT.

Comment: I setup an article series about reading an EMV (e.g. Credit Cards) - this may help you in all of your questions (Android Java sourcecode is included): https://medium.com/@androidcrypto/talk-to-your-credit-card-android-nfc-java-d782ff19fc4a